# How to keep CSS/HTML dropdown from showing partially off-page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a pure css/html dropdown menu, the code for which I pretty much stole from [csswizardry here](http://csswizardry.com/demos/css-dropdown/). It works like a charm; the only problem is that, if that menu item is on the far right side of the page, the dropdown items are half-off the page.

I'm working on a javascript solution; is there a way to fix this problem using just CSS?

EDIT: I'm looking for the dropdown content to move to the left so that the dropdown items are fully visible.

Comment: What SHOULD happen? Maybe move the menu further to the left? Can you wrap the content?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I would like the content to move to the left.

Comment: don't think it could be done with css since the menu is absolutely positioned and therefore out of the document flow

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you based it on, instead of

```
#nav li:hover ul { left:0; }
```

...you'd want:

```
#nav li:hover ul { left:auto; right:0; }
```

Looks like you may need to adjust the right margin of `#nav li` if you're using the same CSS as [csswizardry](http://csswizardry.com/demos/css-dropdown/).